# Snake in C# - player can scale window - dividing manual-scaled window into identical squares

Tags: c#

As part of my self-education of programming I decided to make a snake in C#. The problem I have is about the client size of the game form.

I want player to be able to scale the window of the game, which is divided into 25 x 25 grid (every coordinate is like "one pixel") - it means, that at any moment, the window is divided into 25 x 25 identical squares.

The problem I get is near this code:

```
int SquareSide = (ClientSize.Width / 25);
```

When I set the `ClientSize` strictly to for example 600 x 600, which is a multiple of 25, everything goes OK. But when I don't (for example by manual resizing, which can change the size to, for example, 711 x 711), it creates at the right side a 'strip', which seems to be the rest of pixels, which can't be used because we are dividing to integer number.

My question is - is there any not-extremely-hard way to achieve dividing ANY client size of form into 25 x 25 grid without this problem? I tried using `double`, but `FillRectangle` method doesn't accept it.

I hope my question is understandable and thank you for replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell you the truth, there is

```
g.FillRectangle(Brush b, RectangleF rect)
```

`RectangleF` is a rectangle whose coordinates are float.
So you can use:

```
float SquareSide = (ClientSize.Width * 1f / 25);
```

Comment: This is more clear IMO: `float SquareSide = (ClientSize.Width / 25f);`

Comment: @scottm: yes, maybe you're right. Anyway we're talking about syntactical sugar ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would try to simply handle OnResize event of the window, and at the moment user finishes rezise it, force the size that program need for perfect fit of the grid.
So for example at the moment user releases mouse and you figure out that one dimensions of the window 711x711, bring it to nearest correct fit 700x700.

In this way you guarantee good user experience on different monitor resolutions and for you guarantee a correct fit of the grid you draw.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to float coordinates for everything. Make sure your game looks OK when lines do not have whole pixel coordinates. Make sure you "find next cell" code also works with floats, including mouse position detection if needed.

The other approach is to be happy with integer coordinates (and cells of the same size) and make page layout flexible to accomodate some unused space for odd 711x711 layouts (i.e. just center the field and keep some variable width border).